# Rails + Pow + Snow Leopard Server: I can't get Pow to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, osx-server, rack-pow

I'm running Snow Leopard Server 10.6.7, and I need to host some Rails apps locally. Pow seems to be a good fit for what I need, but I can't seem to get it to work. At first, when I went to `http://myapp.dev`, I would get the OS X Server Welcome page. I asked around, and I was told to disable Web Sharing, which I did by turning off Web under Applications > Server > Server Admin. This hasn't helped.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Pow with Web disabled, but that didn't help anything, either. I tried restarting the Pow server by running `touch /mydir/myapp/tmp/restart.txt`, and that's not helped, either.

Comment: In my experience, after turning off web sharing, a restart of the OSX machine is necessary before Pow will spin up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the help carefully to create app? You must do a symlink of your app in ~/.pow

You can also use the gem powify:

- Type 'gem install powify' in term
- Type 'powify' in console and look at powify's help. Hint: cd in your app dir the type "powify create myapp" and then go to http://myapp.dev

Good luck!